# I want to keep order of OrderedDict with ujson

Tags: python, ordereddictionary, ujson

My function's return value type is `OrderedDict`,

and now I want to write this on the file:

Here's my code:

```
mainDict = OrderedDict([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',[4,5,6])])
with open(outFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile :
   outFile.write(ujson.dumps(mainDict, indent=4))
```

I expected it to keep the order of the dictionary in the file, but it got mixed up.

Is it because of using `ujson.dumps`? and how can I keep the order of an `OrderedDict` in the output file?

Comment: json doesn't allow ordered dicts. From json.org: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.". object is the json/javascript equivalent of a Python dict. If you want to keep the order, turn it into a list (json array).

Comment: @Evert, The output order is decided by dict itself, json does not care about it. What json does is calling dict.items() for formatting. OrderedDict.items() which is ordered-aware.

Comment: @sh kim In my side, the output is ordered with `json`. What is ujson, does it equal to json?

Comment: Why do you need to keep the order, what do you do with the json file?

Comment: @Jacky I heard `json` and `ujson` modules are similar so I use `ujson`  without reason.. and like your mention, I just change `ujson` to `json` in my code, then it worked!!! my outfile keeps order I made!!! thanks

Comment: @BiRico usually json file don't need order but these files contain informations of projects and sometimes I have to check this roughly so I wanted to make readable file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use `sort_keys` parameter of `ujson.dumps`

Behaviour of `ujson` is the following:

- `sort_keys=None` (default if omitted) - dump dict keys in implementation-defined order, which may be different every launch (but it's fast)
- `sort_keys=True` - sort dict keys before dump
- `sort_keys=False` - preserve dict keys order provided by `dict.items()`

So to preserve ordering of `OrderedDict` with `ujson`, you need `sort_keys=False`.

---

### Tests

This is how you can check it:

```
import sys
import ujson

order = None
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    order = bool(int(sys.argv[1]))

mainDict = OrderedDict([('c',3),('b',2),('a',1)])
sys.stdout.write(ujson.dumps(mainDict, sort_keys=order))
```

Tests:

```
$ python order.py      # sort_keys=None
{"c":3,"a":1,"b":2}

$ python order.py      # sort_keys=None
{"b":2,"c":3,"a":1}

$ python order.py 1    # sort_keys=True
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}

$ python order.py 0    # sort_keys=False
{"c":3,"b":2,"a":1}
```

---

### Notes

Note that unlike `ujson`, built-in `json` module preserves key order with `sort_keys=None`, as well as with `sort_keys=False`.

Also note that although it's possible to preserve keys order with these implementations (`ujson` and `json`), it's non-standard JSON. See [json.org](http://json.org/:):

> An object is an *unordered* set of name/value pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work as expected, due to a bug in the ujson library [https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/250]. Bug has been claimed to be fixed but not released in a new version since (2 years now!).

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
mainDict = OrderedDict([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',[4,5,6])])
with open(outFileName, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile :
   outFile.write(ujson.dumps(mainDict, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it seems like `ujson` dumps the dictionary as an unordered dictionary by default, unlike the built-in `json` package. Set the `sort_keys` argument to `true` to dump the data as an ordered dictionary.

Here's my the sample code:

```
import ujson
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

mainDict = OrderedDict([('a',1),('b',2),('c',3),('d',[4,5,6])])

# Maintain the ordering of dictionary upon dump.
with open("ordereddict2.txt", 'w') as outFile :
  outFile.write(ujson.dumps(mainDict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: `sort_keys` sorts the input, it doesn't preserve its state. Try this, `json.dumps(OrderedDict([('b','b'), ('a','a')]), sort_keys=True)`.

Comment: Note, with json.dumps, you don't have to use `sort_keys=True` if the current state of the dictionary is in the order that you want.

Comment: "Without the sort_keys set to True, the dictionary will loose its order upon dump." -- this is incorrect, see my answer

Comment: Please read what I wrote carefully. My answer is correct. I did state with `ujson` you must use `sort_keys`. However, if u already sorted the json, you can use `json` without the `sort_keys`.